# Is $f(x) = e^x$ a Surjective function?

Tags: functions

If it is not possible to draw a horizontal line across the graph of a function without making contact with the curve representing the function then the function is surjective.

So, $f(x)=x^3$ is a surjectve function. But, $f(x)=x^2$ is not a surjectve function.

Then what about $f(x) = e^x$? Is it a Surjective function?

Why and why not?

Comment: Does it intersect the $-1$ line?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ is not surjective onto the reals because for any negative number $a < 0$ there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = a < 0$. Ask a similar question of $f(x) = e^x$

Answer (score 7):

It depends. $e^x:\Bbb R\to(0,\infty)$ is a surjection while $e^x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is not.

According to you definition of "surjectivity", it'd be a nice idea to lookup an image of $f(x)=e^x$. It's kinda like a curve that stays on the upper half plane while never touching the $x$-axis. 
[image: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/interactive/ExpReal.gif]

Comment: OP gave their informal definition of surjective. I think you should at least present that  interpretation more prominently.  It'd also "depend" for $x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've edited my post to address the issue. By the way, how do we include an image into a post?

Comment: Thanks for following up. For the image when editing: there is an icon to click  that looks a bit like a photo, right next to the {} symbol. Click it and follow the instructions.